# Float Layout in CSS

Tags: css, css-float

I have a basic testimonial layout that I have designed and coded. I am having a bit of trouble getting the floated elements to work correctly though. The issue is that because the top left is longer than the top right, the third quote nests under the right side instead of the left. If I clear: both on it, then the fourth quote lines up with the third instead of tucking underneath the second quote. I also thought I could use some basic jQuery and add a float: left to all the even quotes and a float: right to all the odd, but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Also, I know I could just reposition the quotes and make it work. The problem is that the client will keep adding quotes that I don't know the length, so I need to make it work even in the worst possible scenario. Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: You used JQuery to add `float:left;` to even and `float:right` to odd, even when there are CSS selectors to do this: `.class:nth-of-type(even);` or `.class:nth-of-type(odd);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ta2Uc/).

HTML:

```
<div id="column1">
    <div class="item">
       <!-- ITEM CONTENT -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       <!-- ITEM CONTENT -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       <!-- ITEM CONTENT -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="column2">
    <div class="item">
       <!-- ITEM CONTENT -->      
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       <!-- ITEM CONTENT -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       <!-- ITEM CONTENT -->       
    </div>    
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS

```
#column1, #column2
{
    width: 48%;
}
#column1
{
     float: left;
}
#column2
{
    float: right;
}
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
.item
{
    background: #FE63E4;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, this might work and I thought about columns, but then how would they add this to a CMS? Would you still be able to even though you would have to add them to column 1 then column 2 alternating? Does that make sense?

Comment: @Andrew: You should be able to do this. If the items are contained in an array, you should be able to divide the array in half and put half in each column.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I could not find any solution for my problem. After many hours of trying to solve it easily, I finally create solution works for me. It is made mainly in JQuery, but I think, you can modify it easily to another js framework. I am not specialist on javascript, so code will be probably not optimalised.

HTML (only for illustration)

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="level-top">
    <a href="#"><span>Item 1</span></a>
    <ul class="level0">
      <li class="level1">
        <a href="#"><span>Item 2</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="level1">
        <a href="#"><span>Item 3</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS (only for illustration)

```
ul#nav { display:block; }
li.level-top { position:relative; float:left; width:120px; height:50px; }
li.level-top a { display:block; height:50px; line-height:50px; }
ul.level0 {
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:0;
  padding:9px 0;
  border:3px solid #CCC;
  width:240px;
  display:none;
}
li.level-top:hover ul.level0 { display:block; }
li.level1 { position:absolute; width:120px; }
li.level1.odd { left:0; }
li.level1.even { right:0; }
```

JS
My main problem solved here. UL element with class level0 is normally hidden. We need to display it out of screen and set top positioning of both columns and then return it back.

```
(function($){ // start jquery
$(document).ready(function(){ // domready

$("#nav > li > ul > li:nth-child(odd)").addClass('odd'); // This add class="odd" to every odd li in ul.level0
$("#nav > li > ul > li:nth-child(even)").addClass('even'); // This add class="even" to every even li in ul.level0

$('ul.level0').each(function(index) { // get all ul elements with level0 class
  $(this).css('top', '-5000px').css('display', 'block'); // hide out of screen before changes and make display:block to possiblity of get heights of elements
  var topPadding = parseInt($(this).css('padding-top')); // get padding-top (only numeric value) of ul element

  var leftHeight = 0; // start left column from 0 (top position)
  $(this).children('li.level1.odd').each(function(index) { // get odd elements
    var $liOuterHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true); // get height of li element (height with padding, border and margin)
    $(this).css('top', (leftHeight+topPadding)+'px'); // set top position of li element
    leftHeight += $liOuterHeight; // modify height of left column
  });

  var rightHeight = 0; // start right column from 0 (top position)
  $(this).children('li.level1.even').each(function(index) { // get even elements
    var $liOuterHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true); // get height of li element (height with padding, border and margin)
    $(this).css('top', (rightHeight+topPadding)+'px'); // set top position of li element
    rightHeight += $liOuterHeight; // modify height of right column
  });

  $(this).height(rightHeight > leftHeight ? rightHeight : leftHeight).css('top', '').css('display', ''); // set height to ul element and change back all css changes (positioning + display)
});

}); // end of domready
})(jQuery); // end of jquery
```

I hope, it helps somebody. This was made for menu, which was normally hidden. I think, you can modify it for anything else. It's not so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

See this example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e4abB/3/

```
<!--Left Column Boxes-->
<div style="width:50%; float:left">
  <div style="background-color:#f00; width:100%; height:50px;">left1</div>
  <div style="background-color:#0f0; width:100%;">left2</div>
  <div style="background-color:#00f; width:100%;">left3</div>
</div>

<!--Right Column Boxes-->
<div style="float:right; width:50%">
  <div style="background-color:#aaa; width:100%;">right1</div>
  <div style="background-color:#ff0; width:100%;">right2</div>
  <div style="background-color:#0ff; width:100%; height:40px;">right3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the other answers, they're right. You *could* use your server-side code to split the items into two seperate columns, no problem. I simply wasn't considering server-side code when I wrote my answer.

---

Because the quotes could be any height, I don't believe there is a general purpose CSS method available.

Especially because you said:

> **I need to make it work even in the
>   worst possible scenario.**

You should instead use the [**jQuery Masonry**](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) plugin.

[image]

Comment: I knew there was some sort of jQuery plugin for this sort of thing. I think I am going to present the client with both options, one with the CSS columns and one with jQuery Masonry. Thanks for the help!